# Module '"@turf/turf"' has no exported member 'transformScale'

Tags: next.js, types, turfjs

I'm having a bit of difficulty using this Turf module, others like polygon work perfectly.

I've tried in various ways and they all say the module doesn't exist. I deleted the node_modules and package-lock.json and still couldn't use it.

What am I doing wrong?

```json
{
  "@turf/transform-scale": "^6.5.0",
  "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
}
```

```js
import { transformScale } from '@turf/turf'
```

No.

```js
import { transformScale as turfTransformScale } from '@turf/turf'
```

No.

```js
import turf from '@turf/turf'
```

No.

Project is a Next.js based (default typescript template).

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "walk-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.445.0",
    "@googlemaps/markerclusterer": "^2.5.1",
    "@googlemaps/react-wrapper": "^1.1.35",
    "@turf/circle": "^6.5.0",
    "@turf/transform-scale": "^6.5.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "@upstash/redis": "^1.25.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.2.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.15.0",
    "next": "^14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.10",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.54.7",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.7.18",
    "@types/node": "^20.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/turf": "^3.5.32",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.ts`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing it like this should work:

```
import transformScale from '@turf/transform-scale';
```